# ARKit - How to get z distance from current camera position

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have an `ARSCNView` that allows users to draw in 3d space. The drawing looks fine if we look at it from the camera angle where we drew it like in [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg4Mh.png). But when I look at it from another camera angle, it looks out of shape like in [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5DRz.png). Of course, users would expect the ring to not change shape if they look at it from a different angle.

The following code is:

1. Getting the touch point in 2d using a gesture recognizer
2. Finding the corresponding 3d point using `hitTest` method on `sceneView`
3. Asking to draw a line from the previous point to the current point.

Code

```
@objc func panGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    gestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1

    let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view), types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint)
    guard let result = results.first else {
      return
    }

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
      vector1 = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
      let vector2 = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

      guard let vector1 = vector1 else {
        self.vector1 = vector2
        return
      }

      let line = lineFrom(vector: vector1, toVector: vector2)
      let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)
      sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)

      self.vector1 = vector2
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
      vector1 = nil
    }
  }
```

I think I need to normalize the horizontal distance from the current device position to each point in the drawing. I tried to do this by changing this line:

```
let vector2 = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
```

to:

```
let vector2 = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, vector1.z - currentCameraPositionRelativeToOrigin.z - currentCameraRotation.z)
```

But this only made the problem worse. I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Edit: Here is the code that draws the actual line segments:

```
class func lineThrough(points: [SCNVector3], width:Int = 20, closed: Bool = false,  color: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor, mitter: Bool = false) -> SCNGeometry {

    // Becouse we cannot use geometry shaders in metal, every point on the line has to be changed into 4 verticles
    let vertices: [SCNVector3] = points.flatMap { p in [p, p, p, p] }

    // Create Geometry Source object
    let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)

    // Create Geometry Element object
    var indices = Array((0..<Int32(vertices.count)))
    if (closed) {
        indices += [0, 1]
    }
    let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangleStrip)

    // Prepare data for vertex shader
    // Format is line width, number of points, should mitter be included, should line create closed loop
    let lineData: [Int32] = [Int32(width), Int32(points.count), Int32(mitter ? 1 : 0), Int32(closed ? 1 : 0)]

    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    geometry.setValue(Data(bytes: lineData, count: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size*lineData.count), forKeyPath: "lineData")

    // map verticles into float3
    let floatPoints = vertices.map { float3($0) }
    geometry.setValue(NSData(bytes: floatPoints, length: MemoryLayout<float3>.size * floatPoints.count), forKeyPath: "vertices")

    // map color into float
    let colorFloat = color.components!.map { Float($0) }
    geometry.setValue(NSData(bytes: colorFloat, length: MemoryLayout<simd_float1>.size * color.numberOfComponents), forKey: "color")

    // Set the shader program
    let program = SCNProgram()
    program.fragmentFunctionName = "thickLinesFragment"
    program.vertexFunctionName = "thickLinesVertex"
    geometry.program = program

    return geometry
}
```